# Use Environment variables Inside node.conf files in corda

Tags: properties, environment-variables, corda

I created a node.conf files for all nodes including notary but currently I am using hard-coded value for hostname and port and I want to know is there any way to use environment variables inside a node.conf files so that only can change the value in the file that contains those environment variables and updated inside a node.conf file.

I am assuming there should be way like I have one file config.properties where I can specify key-value pairs e.g.
`host=xxx.xx.xx.x`
`port=8080`

then simply can use these variables inside node.conf file like `p2pAddress="${host}:${port}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I do not think you can do this. You can have cordapp specific configuration (https://docs.corda.net/head/cordapp-build-systems.html#cordapp-configuration-files) but this does not seem to be what you are talking about.

I might be missing something, but I am also unsure of why you would need to do this. The values in the `node.conf` file are only going to be used for setting up the node and not retrieved by the cordapps themselves.

Comment: I am trying to deploy nodes on different systems based on IP address specified so If I can use environment variables inside `node.conf` file then I only need to do changes in my `.properties` file where all different variables will be present.

Comment: I think something like ansible would be useful for this. You can then define the hosts and ports you want and allow ansible to go through and replace the required files and place them on the various vms.